# Link XYZ company users to slack

Tags: slack

So suppose that I work for  XYZ company which wants to use slack or rather to integrate the Slack API in the web and desktop application. So the question is that we have a bunch of users and as I know the user object has a user-id. So my question is can we the user -id from the user's email? Or, what do we need to do for a user to easily link their Slack as they wouldn't know their user-id?

Comment: What do you mean by "link their Slack"? Do you mean a link on a website to their Profile in the Slack user directory?

Comment: I mean link their slack account to their existing Email from the XYZ company say like a person has an email id as abcname@xyz.com and he/she wants to have a slack too so can he/she do it without creating a new slack account like we do for certain apps by sign in using facebook or google?

Comment: @srishtijaiswal have a look at this article for single-sign on information: https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/203772216-SAML-single-sign-on

Comment: @AdilB Could you please guide me on how to create desktop app or web app so that it has a button and when you click on the button it authenticates you as a user of Slack say the Admin of Slack application and lets you send message to that channel but through this app that we created and the message shows up on that channel or as an Im to a particular user on the Slack channel

Comment: That sounds like a new question - please ask another question so everyone can help you out

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking about getting a Slack User ID from a user's registered email address. If so, you can look up Slack User IDs via an email address [by using the `users.lookupByEmail` Slack API method.](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.lookupByEmail)

Comment: Oh well, my question was not this but this too helps because this was my next question after my first. Sorry I am still very new to Slack so did not exactly know how to frame the question